# Corpus of ChatGPT 4.0 responses

Tags: data-request, corpora, computing

Does anyone have a repository of ChatGPT 4.0 responses (along with their prompts)?

I want English non-fiction (especially technical writing), which could include subjects like programming, science, or linguistics (but not ChatGPT-written poetry), ideally with the subject being marked somehow. I would also like the creation date for each response, given that the model is updated every so often and to know how the response was generated (e.g., API vs website, with any additional settings noted if used).

This is for personal use so I don't need any particular license (if it's even legal to relicense AI content) but I am looking for something free that has as many responses as possible. (And something better than making my own or asking one of the people I know who has 4.0 for their data.)

Answer (score 1):

Puffin dataset available on Hugging Face which contains responses from Model using GPT-4. You can [access here](https://huggingface.co/datasets/LDJnr/Puffin) on Hugging Face. It contains 3000 examples from Math, Physics, Biology, Chemistry, Culture, Logic and Roleplay.

Comment: Having only one real column with no subject tag is unfortunate, but I can work with it. Anyway, for any curious, "Roleplay" seems to refer to prompts like "You are a choose-your-own-adventure story writer. You write interesting and fun stories. Only use vocabulary that a 9 year old would understand…"